# How to take a value from input month tag and filter the specific month data in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the timestamp data which comes from the database. Now I need to filter only the specific month data from that.

Here is my input timestamp data:

```
$scope.myData=["2020-05-21 12:31:08",
               "2020-06-22 12:31:08",
               "2020-06-25 12:31:08",
               "2020-07-21 12:31:08",
               "2020-07-25 12:31:08"];
```

I want to filter the specific month data from the above input, when I selected the that Month in the input tag. As shown below :

```
<input type="month" ng-model="myMonth" placeholder="Select Month :"/>
<table>
     <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="d in myData|filter:myMonth">
         <td>{{d}}</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

If I selected June 2020 in input tag, Then I should get output like :

```
Date
2020-06-22 12:31:08
2020-06-25 12:31:08
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using the recent version of AngularJS, which is v1.8.0

From the docs for [input[month]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bmonth%5D), it says that the ng-model will be a Date object.
The array myData contains a string.

What I would suggest is to define a [custom comparator function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#filter-arguments) for the filter:

```js
$scope.compareYearAndMonth = function(a, b) {
  a = new Date(a);
  return a.getFullYear() === b.getFullYear() && a.getMonth() === b.getMonth();
}
```

and use it in the ng-repeat as follows:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="d in myData | filter:myMonth:compareYearAndMonth">
  <td>{{ d }}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the working solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/h78cleQ8EZiUKTc2